# how to write code for -matchcommand for ttk::matchbox

Tags: combobox, tcl, tile, ttk

There is a enhancement for ttk::combobox called ttk::matchbox at http://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/fsdialog/wiki?name=matchbox+manual+page

But there is no document on how to write code for -matchcommand.

Can someone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the widget, I thought the explanation on the manual page was quite clear. You write a proc that gets as input argument the string the user has typed. The proc returns a list of choices that make sense for that string.

As ttk::matchbox was written as a helper widget for ttk::fsdialog, you could also look at those sources to see how it is used.

Example #1 - Show files starting with the string the user has typed:

```
proc filematch {str} {
    return [glob -nocomplain -- $str*]
}
```

The version in ttk::fsdialog is more elaborate, because this one may not work correctly when there are files with ? or * in the name.

Example #2 - Show cities that contain the string the user typed (assuming the global variable cities contains a list of cities to choose from:

```
proc citymatch {str} {
    global cities
    return [lsearch -all -inline -regexp $cities (?iq)$str]
}
```

Using regexp matching here to find the string anywhere in the city name, but with the (?iq) embedded options to ignore case and wildcards.

Comment: Is it a command name or a command prefix? This matters because in the first case the core method of calling is basically `$cmd $param` whereas in the other it is `{*}$pfx $param`.

Comment: As implied by the description in the manual page that "the command specified via the -matchcommand option is invoked with one **additional** argument", it's a command prefix.